# C# The type 'XXXX' cannot be resolved

Tags: c#

I've included a custom validator and included the refrence to the DLL. But I'm getting error below:

```
Warning: System.ArgumentException: The type 'Custom.Validator, CustomValidators, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.
```

I've got a custom.Validator class which is used for custom validation in Enterprise Library.

The following code results the above error:

> var results=results = Validation.Validate(msg);

Could someone please tell me how to fix this error message.

Thank you

Comment: do you have some portion of the code that throws the exception ?

Comment: We cannot help you without the code causing this warning.  Its only a warning so you coudl if you wanted ignore it.

Comment: hhi @yas4891, I've added the code that throws exceptoin

Comment: Is the assembly "CustomValidators" in your \bin\Debug folder? (If you're running this from VS with `Debug` project setttings)

Comment: Thanks @yas4891, I had renamed the CustomValidators hence the error message is popping up.

Answer (score 3):

A couple sanity check things first -- I'm assuming you've added a reference to the correct assembly, right? (your project -> references -> Add Reference, then browse to the assembly). I would use a tool like Reflector to verify the namespace that exists in the referenced assembly.

If you're still running into problems, I had a similar issue where it turned out that I needed to change the "Target Framework" to be ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". (project properties -> application -> target framework)

Comment: +1 for the second part of your answer. That's often the reason for this error, although the message really doesn't communicate it.

Comment: thanks @JohnD, I tried your solution still same error.